# PHP y PHPMyAdmin no encuentra texto

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Estoy intentando crear una pagina en PHP que arrastre desde mysql los datos de un tabla, pero al pasar la variable y recuperarla con $_GET['id'], hay ciertos tipos de datos que no me los encuentra.

En la tabla hay números de clientes como por ejemplo 1921252, para este tipo no tengo ningún problema, el problema lo tengo cuando el cliente tiene mas de una dirección y en la base de datos esta almacenado como 1921252/1, 1921252/2, 1921252/3, etc... esos cliente con barras no consigo que los arrastre mysql.
Este es el código que tengo:

```
<?php
include("conexion.php");
include("include/header.php");


$sql="SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE numero={$_GET['id']}";
$resultado=$conexion->query($sql);
$ro = $resultado->fetch_assoc();

?>
```

Posteriormente viene el código HTML y los demás códigos de la base de datos dependiendo de id que hayamos enviado a la variable.
Podríais ayudarme?

Gracias
Saludos.

Comment: Suena a un problema en la codificación del id. La barra oblicua se codifica en las cadenas de query como %2F. ¿Has probado usar `html_entity_encode` y `html_entity_decode` para codificar y decodificar las cadenas?

Comment: ¿El campo `numero` de la BD tiene datos guardados estilo `12345/6`?. Si es así, entonces es una columna tipo string (`varchar`). En ese caso el sql debe ir: `"...WHERE numero='{$_GET['id']}'"`;

Comment: Gracias a los dos por contestar, lo he solucionado como indica el compañero @aeportugal, añadiendo las comillas simples. Muy agradecido.

Comment: Nada que ver lo que voy a decir, pero guardar multiples direcciones para un cliente,agregandole una barra al numero de cliente, es un serio problema de diseño de base de datos. dicho esto, @aeportugal pones como respuesta lo tu comentario?

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo con @gbianchi, el problema principal aquí es un grave error de diseño. Deberías considerar seriamente normalizar esto, trasladando las posibles direccioens de un usuario a otra tabla. Por poner un ejemplo: si mañana necesitas saber cuántas direcciones tiene cada cliente, ¿cómo lo encontrarás? O, ¿cuántos clientes viven en una determinada ciudad?

Comment: Pilas que si dejas el código así, estás sujeto a inyección SQL https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%c3%b3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%c3%b3n-sql-en-php

Answer (score 2):

¿El campo `numero` de la BD tiene datos guardados estilo `12345/6`?.

Si es así, entonces debe ser una columna tipo *string* (`varchar`). 
En ese caso hay que agregar comillas simples. El `$sql` sería:

```
"...WHERE numero='{$_GET['id']}'";
```

PD. Como menciona gbianchi en los comentarios, un cliente debería tener un índice único. Si el cliente tiene múltiples items característicos (en este caso direcciones), se usa otra tabla para ese item, relacionada a la tabla de clientes. Esto se conoce como [Normalización de bases de datos](https://www.google.com/search?q=normalizaci%C3%B3n+base+de+datos), y es una buena práctica en modelado de bases de datos relacionales.

Comment: yo cambiaria el es buena practica, por es obligatorio para que todo funcione correctamente.... +1 ;)

Comment: Gracias por vuestros comentarios, intentaré realizar otra tabla relacionada con los clientes que tendrán varias direcciones.